# CSS text positioning isn't changing

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position a text on a contentslider. Sadly it seems like nothing could change the text `margin` to what I want it to be.

Actually it does look like: https://gyazo.com/dd9ef0f78b5caaf7a582d9825955284b

Live Preview: http://projects.helpful.ninja/BlackzDesignz/Template_1/index.php

This is how I want it to look: https://gyazo.com/631efa979e78732c2c817fb2abf08716

Css code:

```
#fc_slider_wrap,
#fc_slider_wrap * {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
}

#fc_slider_wrap {
    width: 755px;
    height: 239px;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 11px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#fc_slider_img {
    width: 550px;
    height: 239px;
    z-index: 50;
    clip: rect(0 0 550px 287px);
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#fc_slider_slide > div > span {
    display: none;
}

#fc_slider_slide {
}

#fc_slider_slide > div {
    border-radius: 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#fc_slider_slide > div > img {
    display: block;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

#fc_slider_nav {
    width: 203px;
    height: 287px;
    float: right;
}

#fc_slider_nav > div {
    height: 47px;
    width: 198px;
    background: url(../fc_slider/img/nav_opt_bg.png) repeat-x left top transparent;
    padding-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#fc_slider_nav > div.active {
    background-image: url(../fc_slider/img/nav_opt_bg_h.png);
    color: #212121;
}

#fc_slider_nav > div > img {
    float: left;
    margin: 2px;
    margin-top: 11px;
}

#fc_slider_nav > div > span {
    line-height: 15px;
    padding: 2px 12px 2px 0;
    text-align: left;

}

#fc_slider_caption {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 530px;
    background: url(../fc_slider/img/black_semi.png) repeat left top transparent;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 2px;
    z-index: 50;
}

#fc_slider_pause {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    left: 4px;
    top: 4px;
    z-index: 50;
}
```

Does anyone have a idea, what I'm doing wrong? Apreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `Top:5px; position:relative;` in `#fc_slider_nav > div > span` should make it work